# Best way to collect GPS points periodically in android without draining battery?

Tags: android, gps

Could someone help me with a sample program on this?
How to get a location with an interval of 15 min?

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
final String bestProvider1 = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            bestProvider1,
            75000,
            1, GPSLocationService.this);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider1);'
```

Answer (score 1):

for getting the location in every 15 minutes in the above code modify your code from

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider1,75000,1, GPSLocationService.this);
```

to this:-

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider1,900000,1, GPSLocationService.this);
```

but it would be better if you use the fused location provider

Comment: The problem with fused provider is it won't work on any device with a custom ROM (unless they pirate the Play libraries) or any device that doesn't pay Google a license fee.  I'd avoid it unless you have another dependency on Play Services already.

Comment: yes the problem with the fused location provider is you need to use play services,if you do not want to use play services then your only option left is location providers and the code above as i mentioned gives you update in every 15 minutes,please mark it as accepted

Comment: I can't, I'm not the asker.  I'll throw you an upvote though, your answer is right.

Comment: Could you please give an example for Fused location?